# BigQuery SQL query taking over 10 minutes to load

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

No other queries are taking this long to load, but this one takes over 13 minutes to query the table. Even when I limit the returned rows. Any help would be appreciated.

```
    SELECT
cs.AccountDescriptiveName AS Account,
c.AdvertisingChannelType AS CampaignType,
c.CampaignName as Campaign,
IEEE_DIVIDE(s.AverageCpc, 1000000) AS CPC,
s.Clicks,
s.Impressions,
s.Ctr,
IEEE_DIVIDE(s.Cost, 1000000) AS COST,
s.Date,
s.Device,
s.Conversions,
CAST(s.ConversionValue AS INT64) AS ConversionValue,
s.ConversionRate,
s.DayOfWeek,
s.HourOfDay
FROM
 `client_google_ads.CS_table` AS cs
  LEFT JOIN `client_google_ads.C_table` AS c 
      ON cs.CampaignId = c.CampaignId
  LEFT JOIN `client_google_ads.S_table` AS s ON cs.CampaignId = s.CampaignId
WHERE cs.ExternalCustomerId = 6393800000 OR cs.ExternalCustomerId = 2967200000 OR cs.ExternalCustomerId = 8935000000
ORDER BY s.Date DESC
```

Comment: Are you *sure* this is SQL Server? The fact that you have tagged [tag:google-bigquery] as well, use `INT64` as a data type, back ticks `\`` as quote identifiers, and have a function `IEEE_DIVIDE` (which doesn't exist in T-SQL), strongly suggests not.

Comment: `SELECT ExternalCustomerId, count(*) FROM client_google_ads.CS_table WHERE cs.ExternalCustomerId in(6393800000,2967200000,8935000000) group by ExternalCustomerId` ?

Comment: @richard.harris . . . How many rows are being returned?  My guess is that your `join` conditions are not correct.  Without sample data it is hard to tell.

Comment: @Larnu Its Google Big Query, those tags are removed now.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, after it processes about 1.7M rows, are returned. I have some other tables that return quite a few more rows of data that process in under 20 seconds.

Comment: @richard.harris . .  . The issue may be the ordering.  BigQuery isn't so good at that (i.e. does not parallelize the sort).

Comment: Check "#4 The power of X-ray vision" on this article (https://towardsdatascience.com/10-top-tips-unleash-your-bigquery-superpowers-c87488621c71). Can you share with us a screenshot of the execution details of your query?  (prefer the old UI) (also ORDER BY is probably not needed when you are returning 1.7M rows)